# Fixing git object headers

Tags: git

I have a git repository that is not corrupt (all object files remains, i can commit to it and so on).

Recently I noticed that some older commits are broken, "error in commit":

```
git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
error in commit 1e04e033e642f9310bd7b0e6745f3ef775a15f15: invalid author/committer line - bad email
```

I had a look at the individual commit:

```
zpipe -d < .git/objects/1e/04e033e642f9310bd7b0e6745f3ef775a15f15
commit 276tree 591e98a0b53880a22f18f5bedefe133166d3e67d
parent 4c33ebce11897dd52528defa41890eabc59135e3
author Martin Lindhe <martin@xxx.se
> 1382869510 +0100
committer Martin Lindhe <martin@xxx.se
> 1382869510 +0100

commit message
```

As seen here, the emails have a trailing newline (0x0a, as shown by piping to xxd)

Is it possible to fix the object header?

Comment: Please checkout: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git

Comment: alpertek: Thanks, but git-filter-branch also fails with the same error message, "invalid author/committer line - bad email" (i had it mentioned in an older version of this question but just removed it to try to make the question easier to comprehend)

Answer (score 0):

**Before everything, make a backup of your local repository.**

Suppose your corrupted commit is `<corrupted>`.

First of all, create a new commit object based on the corrupted one:

```
git commit-tree -m "New message line 1" -m "Line 2" <corrupt>^{tree} -p <corrupt>^1
```

**Note: adapt your command (-p for parents to add, -m for commit message lines, etc). See git-commit-tree man page to deal with author name/email etc.**

You will get a new commit SHA-1: `<fixed>`.

Now make a commit replacement (graft):

```
git replace <corrupted> <fixed>
```

This will make a "graft" which will artificially change your corrupted commit with the fixed one.

This modification is reversible: you can remove it or show it through `git-replace` command (see its man page!) or looking into `.git/refs/replace/` directory.

To make it permanent, use `git filter-branch` **but all the changed part will be made of new commit objects (that is, new SHA-1s)**.

```
# HEAD should point to the most recent commit (certainly master)...
git filter-branch <fixed>~1..HEAD
```

Finally, delate your replacement (now permanent in your history):

```
git replace -d <corrupted>
```

This works well with one master branch, but if you have several active branches (created after <corrupted>), you will have to rebase all of them like this:

```
git rebase --onto <new-root-branch> <old-root-branch> <branch>
```

Where:

- `<new-root-branch>` is the commit from which the branch should start now (new base SHA-1);
- `<old-root-branch>` is the commit from which the branch started before the filter branch call;
- `<branch>` is the branch to rebase.

Find these SHA-1s with log commands like:

```
git log --graph --decorate --all --pretty=oneline
```

**When you double checked that everything is OK (branches, etc.) and when everybody linked to your git repository is completely aware of what is going on, you can `git push --force`** your modifications.